# Correct regex to detect font family names from google font link src

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I've been trying to get array of the fonts that I'm enqeueing on my wordpress theme. This is just for testing.

On input:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Quicksand:400,700|Cantarell:400,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:300,400,300italic,400italic|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Share:400,700,400italic,700italic|Inconsolata:400,700|Karla:400,700,400italic,700italic|Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700
```

What I need on output is like this:

```
array(
[0] => 'Arimo',
[1] => 'Quicksand',
[2] => 'Cantarell',
... so on
)
```

Till now, I have done almost everything but one little problem.

My code:

```
$input = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Quicksand:400,700|Cantarell:400,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:300,400,300italic,400italic|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Share:400,700,400italic,700italic|Inconsolata:400,700|Karla:400,700,400italic,700italic|Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700';

$against = "/[A-Z][a-z]+[\+][A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+/";

$matches = array()

preg_match_all( $against, $input, $matches );

print_r($matches);
```

From this, the output is like this:

```
array(
0   =>  Arimo
1   =>  Quicksand
2   =>  Cantarell
3   =>  Muli
4   =>  Roboto+Slab
5   =>  Share
6   =>  Inconsolata
7   =>  Karla
8   =>  Maven+Pro
9   =>  Roboto+Slab
10  =>  Open+Sans
)
```

There's the `+` sign where the font name has spaces. I want to get rid of that.

I'm not a regex expert. So, couldn't manage to do that.

**Note: I know I could do it with `str_replace()` but don't want to go through that long process. I want to know if it's possible to escape the `+` sign through and leave an empty space there when we are collecting matched expressions.**

Comment: In my humble opinion, you'll at a moment or an other need to use a **replacing** function since you call only a match function. You can call it before preg_match, either after preg_match on each element of your array. As preg_replace() costs more than str_replace() in a general manner, you might need to use it.

Comment: I was hoping if it's possible through the search. Maybe on the regex we search for a + sign but write an empty space instead. Is it possible?

Comment: `str_replace()` is not a long process.

Comment: have you got any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Spaces encoded as plus (+) signs in url. You should decode your url.

```
$input = urldecode($input);
```

Comment: Yes that did the job! after using urldecode, changed the regex to "/[A-Z][a-z]+[\s][A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+/" and it's working now. But still wanted to learn if it's possible through regex search. If it's possible, I could learn something new here.
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have more than `+` characters to worry about.

Special characters, such as the ampersand (`&`), and non-ASCII characters in URL query parameters have to be escaped using [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) (`%xx`). In addition, when an HTML form is submitted, spaces are encoded using the `+` character.

For example:

- The font family "Jacques & Gilles" would be escaped as:

  `Jacques+%26+Gilles`
- The Unicode character `U+1E99 (LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH RING ABOVE)`, serialized into octets as UTF-8 (`E1` `BA` `99`), would be escaped as:

  `%e1%ba%99`

---

To do what you want *properly*, you have to extract the query string from the URL, and use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to extract the `name=value` pairs. The `parse_str()` function will automatically [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) the names and values including the `+` characters.

First, split the URL on the `?` character to extract the query string:

```
$url = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|...|Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700|...';

$a = explode ('?', $url, 2);
if (isset ($a[1])) {
  $query = $a[1];
}
```

You can also use [`parse_url ($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), but it doesn't buy you much in this case.

Then extract all the parameters:

```
if (isset ($query)) {
  parse_str ($query, $params);

  if (isset ($params['family'])) {
    /* OK: Extract family names. */
  } else {
    /* Error: No family parameter found. */
  }
} else {
  /* Error: No query string found. */
}
```

**Note:** You should always specify the second parameter of `parse_str()` to avoid clobbering existing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
$query = strtr(substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY),7), '+', ' ');

$result = array_map(function ($i) { return explode(':', $i)[0]; }, explode('|', $query));
```

With regex:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|[^?&]+[?&]family=)([^:|&]+):[^:|&]*(?:[|&#]|\z)~', strtr($url, '+', ' '), $m))
   $result2 = $m[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, output is given me something like this.

```
array([0] => array([0]   =>  Arimo[1]   =>  Quicksand[2]   =>  Cantarell[3]   =>  Muli[4]   =>  Roboto+Slab[5]   =>  Share[6]   =>  Inconsolata[7]   =>  Karla[8]   =>  Maven+Pro[9]   =>  Roboto+Slab[10]  =>  Open+Sans))
```

if is correct, then i was solve this issue '+'. here is the solution.

```
$input = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Quicksand:400,700|Cantarell:400,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:300,400,300italic,400italic|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Share:400,700,400italic,700italic|Inconsolata:400,700|Karla:400,700,400italic,700italic|Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700';

$against = "/[A-Z][a-z]+[\+][A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+/";

$matches = array();
$newArr=array();
preg_match_all( $against, $input, $matches );

for($i=0;$i< count($matches);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j< count($matches[$i]);$j++){
        $string=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $matches[$j]);
        if($string!=""){
            $newArr[]=$string;
        }
    }    
}
print_r($newArr);
```